# Can a minor be bound to a contract if a parent co-signs?

Tags: united-states, contract-law, minor, oregon

James Doe, John Doe's minor son, wants to sign a contract with Mary Smith, an adult. Is the contract binding on James if he and his father both sign it? What if only his father signs it, but makes it clear he is signing on behalf of James? Assume that this is a contract that would clearly be voidable by James if only he had signed it.

Comment: A contract about what? The child can legally enter a contract on its own, if it's old enough and of reasonable value (e.g. buy sweets with one's allowance). Note: not all contracts need to be in writing,  most do not.

Comment: I'm not thinking of any specific contract, just any written contract that would ordinarily not be binding on a minor.

Comment: you should edit this to make the point clearer. Use as an example a contract clearly voidable, say to purchase an auto on an installment basis.

Comment: In Colorado, liability waivers have been upheld on those grounds.

Answer (score 2):

### Children can enter contracts

There seems to be this pervading myth that they can’t. This is weird because, if true, it would mean that a child couldn’t buy anything: a chocolate bar, a bus ride, a sandwich, because all sales involve a contract.

What is true is that a contract is voidable by a minor. That is, they can walk away from it anytime until they turn 18 and for a reasonable time thereafter. They can’t do that if the contract is for “necessities” (all of the above examples are), if the contract is complete (again, all of the above) or if the contract is clearly for the benefit of the child (e.g. contracts involving the child’s education).

Children do not normally need a parent’s permission or approval to enter a contract.

So, the contract is binding on Mary and voidable by James. John’s involvement is irrelevant unless he is a party to the contract in some way such as if he is acting as a guarantor.

Comment: Yes, I know that they can enter contracts but can void them. In this case, James does not want to be able to void the contact, because Mary is not willing to sign it if he has that ability.

Comment: I take the question to be, if the contract would otherwise be voidable, will a co-signature of a parent make it non-voidable.

Comment: @DavidSiegel Yes that's exactly what I'm asking.

Comment: There’s also the question if it is the minor who has to carry the cost, or if it is the parent. I’m 17, I saved $1000, and I buy a car for $500 monthly payments. After two months my money is gone and I would like to void the contract. My parent co-signed. Who has to pay the $500 a month?

Comment: @gnasher729 if you void the contract, no one does. That’s what void means.

Comment: My parent co-signed. So presumably they are part of the contract as well. And being adults, they can't void their part of the contract.